# Populate empty cell with a unique value in Google Sheets with Python

Tags: python-3.x, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, gspread

I'm new to using Python with the Google Sheets API and I'm trying to populate a cell with an email address IF that email address does not exist in that cell column.

I have:

```
ws = client.open('Workbook Name').worksheet('Worksheet Name')
ws.update_acell('A2', 'someemail@info.com')
```

Which works fine. Logically speaking, I'd like it to:

```
if email in range(A:A):
    'Email exists'
else:
    update next cell in range(A:A) that is empty
```

Hope that makes sense.

Sample output:

```
    |   A    |
     --------
 1  | email1 |
 2  | email2 |
```

if email3 not in range(A:A) update to next available cell in range(A:A)

```
    |   A    |
     --------
 1  | email1 |
 2  | email2 |
 3  | email3 |
```

I do not want to hardcode (A3). I want to dynamically find the next free cell, preferably with gspread function.

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. I cannot understand about your goal from your question. Can I ask you about the detail of `I'd like it to:`?

Comment: Sorry, to be clear - is there a function in gspread that can check if a value exists in a cell range (e.g. A:A) and if it does not exist, update the next blank cell in range (A:A)

Comment: Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, I couldn't understand about your goal from your replying. This is due to my poor English skill. I deeply apologize for this. In order to correctly understand about your goal, can you provide the sample input and output you expect? By this, I would like to understand about your goal.

Comment: Hello - sample output has been added. Thanks

Comment: Thank you for replying and adding the information. From your additional information, I proposed a sample script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your question and that was not the direction you want, I apologize.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I could not find much documentation on gspread but that is exactly what I needed.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You want to append a value to the column "A" when the value is not found in the column "A".
- You want to achieve this using gspread with python.
- You have already been able to get and put values for Google Spreadsheet with Sheets API.

In this answer, the values are retrieved by the method of `col_values()`, and the value is appended using `append_row()` method.

#### Sample script:

```
spreadsheetId = "###"  # Please set the Spreadsheet ID.
sheetName = "Sheet1"  # Please set the sheet name.

client = gspread.authorize(credentials)
spreadsheet = client.open_by_key(spreadsheetId)
ws = spreadsheet.worksheet(sheetName)
value = "email3"
if value not in ws.col_values(1):
    ws.append_row([value], value_input_option="USER_ENTERED")
```

- In this script, when `email3` is not included in the column "A", `email3` is appended to the column "A".

#### References:

- [col_values()](https://gspread.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#gspread.models.Worksheet.col_values)
- [append_row()](https://gspread.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#gspread.models.Worksheet.append_row)